# Text to Columns

Tags: vba, excel, formatting

My Excel file has a SQL connection that runs a stored procedure and outputs three columns, each in a time format. The output is in the "hh:mm:ss" format, which Excel doesn't take as a time. I've found that if I manually use the 'Text to Columns' tool with the default settings, Excel converts '0:03:05' to '12:03:05 AM'. I used VB Code to replicate the Text to Column, but it's only working if it's the only code in a Sub. Currently, this works =

```
 Sub textToColumns()
 Sheets("Main Data").Visible = True
     Sheets("Main Data").Select 
         Sheets("Main Data").Select
     Columns("Z:Z").Select
     Selection.textToColumns Destination:=Range("Z:Z"), _
    DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter _
    :=False, Tab:=True, Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, _
    Other:=False, FieldInfo:=Array(1, 1), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
 Sheets("Main Data").Visible = False   
 End Sub
```

But this does not =

```
 Sub textToColumns()
 ActiveWorkbook.RefreshConnections
 Sheets("Main Data").Visible = True
     Sheets("Main Data").Select 
         Sheets("Main Data").Select
     Columns("Z:Z").Select
     Selection.textToColumns Destination:=Range("Z:Z"), _
    DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter _
    :=False, Tab:=True, Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, _
    Other:=False, FieldInfo:=Array(1, 1), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
 Sheets("Main Data").Visible = False   
 End Sub
```

The only difference is the `ActiveWorkbook.RefreshConnections`

I tried splitting the Refresh and the Text to Columns into two separate Subs and then calling both, but it didn't work.

It's worth noting that I'm not receiving any error messages at all.

Comment: if you run your refresh manually then run the first sub right after it works?

Comment: @ScottHoltzman Yes. I can run the Refresh Sub and the Text to Column sub individually, and both work fine. When I roll the two into each other, the Text to columns does not proc.

Comment: @pnuts I have tried that in 5, 30 and 60 second increments. I don't think the issue is with the amount of time the table takes to refresh (< 2 seconds).

Comment: there are no other workbooks open when you run the code, right?

Comment: @ScottHoltzman Correct.